# Jest testing, keeps return undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test a function with jest, and I simply can figure out what's wrong? It keeps saying it expects to return the output, but got undefined. I have tested the function elsewhere where it seems to return the correct array.

I'm calling my my function and passing it an Object, it's then supposed to return an array. Then I'm calling  .toEqual(output) which is an array.

```
//This is my function
const allAddresses = [
];

const updateAllAddresses = (obj) => {
  const transferAmount = obj.transferAmount;
  const to = obj.to;
  const transferAddress = obj.address;
  const newBalance = obj.newBalance;
  const addressArr = [...allAddresses];
  console.log("This addressArr", addressArr);
  console.log("this is obj", obj);
  //To set your account to the new balance after transfer and
  //to check if the address you transfer to is your own account
  addressArr.map((address) => {
    if (address.account === transferAddress) {
      console.log("This is inside the map !!!!");
      address.balance = Number(newBalance);
    }
    if (address.account === to) {
      console.log("2");
      address.balance = Number(transferAmount) + Number(address.balance);
    }
    console.log("last part of the testing", addressArr);
    return addressArr;
  });
};

const obj = {
};
const output = [
];


//This is my test
describe("Update array", () => {
  test("update the array with the new information", () => {
    expect(updateAllAddresses(obj)).toEqual(output);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot short circuit and return inside a `map` function. You should return the object after the `map`

Also, when you change `address` inside the `map`; It really does not change anything, since that `address` variable will be removed from memory on next iteration

Comment: Arh I see, about the return inside the map! 
I'm sorry but what do you mean regarding the variable will be removed on next iteration? I have used the spread operator to save  the array of objects in the variable.

Comment: `map` does not change the array, it just returns a new array. See [using map js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#examples)

Comment: Of course!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking `✅` button on it. @user16716646

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your `updateAllAddresses` method.
You are not returning anything then the result of your function becomes `undefined`;

add `return` to where you are using .map method.

```
  return addressArr.map((address) => {
    if (address.account === transferAddress) {
      console.log("This is inside the map !!!!");
      address.balance = Number(newBalance);
    }
    if (address.account === to) {
      console.log("2");
      address.balance = Number(transferAmount) + Number(address.balance);
     }
    console.log("last part of the testing", addressArr);
    return address;
  });
```

Comment: But I do return the adressArr on the last line of the function, after I have edited the Array. If i add a return before the map, it add three times undefined and doesn't pass the test.

Comment: No, you are returning the `addressArr` inside the map. and please fix that and put `return` outside of the map and instead of map use `forEach` method. but I will update my post to give you what I'm saying.